# Hiding images and sibling elements when the image doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Sorry, this has likely been answered, but I can't find it.

I'm trying to hide broken external images, using the following

```
$("img").on("error", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

It works perfectly fine, but their titles within the `div` block still show up

```
<div class="something" data-gallery="0">
    <div class="something" data-bg="image_url" >    
        <img src="image_url" alt='something here" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" title="something here'/>
        <div class="something_title" >
            <h3>The title</h3>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div>
```

My issue is, I can't seem to figure out a way to hide the title

```
<div class="something_title" >
    <h3>The title</h3>
</div>
```

In this section, so users don't see an image, but they see a title, and in a gallery, this makes no sense for them.

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+sibling+jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use DOM traversal to target the parent (wrapper) element:

```
$(this).closest('.something').hide();
```

You could also target the sibling directly and separately:

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).siblings('.something_title').hide();
```

I find the first option simpler, though, and it tends to eliminate issues involving leftover margins and padding on the wrapper.

Comment: Hey @iserwood, how could one do this on ```<div class="something" data-bg="image_url" >  ``` being broken    also thank you for your responses.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please ask more clearly and use punctuation.